# Do inbound & outbound links on canonicalized pages carry any SEO weight?

Tags: seo, links, canonical-url, rel-canonical

So, I have a page [A] that has canonical tag with URL pointing to a page [B].

Do inbound & outbound links on page [A] carry any SEO weight if they aren't nofollowed?

Is the weight of links on page [A] the same or lower than the weight of links on page [B]?

Comment: I cannot see a reason why Google would change the algorithm to make exceptions for canonical tags. I cannot see an advantage for the search engine to doing this. Remember code is expensive and has the opportunity to upset an existing ecosystem (lack of a better word). If there is no value to doing something, and Google is always looking for value first, then why do it?

Comment: https://moz.com/beginners-guide-to-seo/basics-of-search-engine-friendly-design-and-development

Comment: Sorry guys, but you both failed to give a clear answer. @closetnoc what do you mean, is it YES or NO?

Comment: I am saying that links would effect any page with canonical tags the same that they would effect any other page. No difference. Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc thank you. If you can give it as an answer, I would mark it as answered.